# Performance of Insight micro-ORM

Tags: dapper, micro-orm

I was wondering if anybody has some metrics on Insight micro-ORM. Its a fairly new ORM, like Dapper but more for stored procs.

Comment: http://code.jonwagner.com/2013/02/05/micro-orm-benchmarks-february-2013/

Answer (score 2):

I ran some benchmarks back in February. The latest version of Insight should have about the same performance as that build. Most of the popular ORMs have about the same speed. Pick the one that suits your style the best.

http://code.jonwagner.com/2013/02/05/micro-orm-benchmarks-february-2013/